Trigger a GeoNetwork harvester using the API
Does anyone know if it is possible to trigger a harvester using the GeoNetwork API?
The Swagger harvest endpoint for harvest, only includes:

POST: Assign harvester records to a new source" &  "GET: Check if a
harvester name or host already exist

I know that you can schedule the harvester to run at a specific time in geonetwork but we have an ETL process and it would be more graceful to trigger the actual harvester when it completes.
